# PHP: How can I access / use a method within its own class?

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how to use a method within its own class. example:

```
class demoClass
{
    function demoFunction1()
    {
        //function code here
    }

    function demoFunction2()
    {
        //call previously declared method
        demoFunction1();
    }
}
```

The only way that I have found to be working is when I create a new intsnace of the class within the method, and then call it. Example:

```
class demoClass
{
    function demoFunction1()
    {
        //function code here
    }

    function demoFunction2()
    {
        $thisClassInstance = new demoClass();
        //call previously declared method
        $thisClassInstance->demoFunction1();
    }
}
```

but that does not feel right... or is that the way?
any help?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$this->` inside of an object, or `self::` in a static context (either for or from a static method).

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [`$this`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) to refer to the current object:

> The pseudo-variable `$this` is available when a method is called from within an object context. `$this` is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

So:

```
class demoClass
{
    function demoFunction1()
    {
        //function code here
    }

    function demoFunction2()
    {
        // $this refers to the current object of this class
        $this->demoFunction1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

```
$this->demoFunction1();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `$this` keyword to refer to current class instance:

```
class demoClass
{
    function demoFunction1()
    {
        //function code here
    }

    function demoFunction2()
    {
        $this->demoFunction1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use "$this" to refer to itself.

```
class demoClass
{
    function demoFunction1()
    {
        //function code here
    }

    function demoFunction2()
    {
        //call previously declared method
        $this->demoFunction1();
    }
}
```