# Can i call own class in php?

Tags: php, class

I don't want to use new in my calling php document. I just want to call `static method`.

For example my class is:

```
class MergeCaching{

    public static function writeList(){
        $write = new MergeCaching();   // I want to use new here
        $write->getListFromRu();
    }

    public function getListFromRu(){
       print_r('Example');
    }
}
```

My calling php document like this:

```
MergeCaching::writeList();
```

It works but can I use like this?

Comment: Maybe this article can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365458/php-how-can-i-access-use-a-method-within-its-own-class.

Comment: Make `getListFromRU` static and then you can it call with `self::getListFromRu()`

Comment: Are you sure you want static? Do you know why you need that?

Comment: Quite honestly, I don't really know what you're asking.

Comment: You might want to read this [New self vs. new static](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about instantiating a class in its context you could do it using `new self`:

```
public static function writeList(){
    $write = new self;
    $write->getListFromRu();
}
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new)

Comment: `new self`? Is that a thing??

Comment: OP's question is about `not` instantiating a class

Comment: @C0dekid Yes it is, `new static()` can be used as well

Comment: Haha learned something new then. I was reading about it now, thanks @deceze ^^.

Comment: @DarkBee What is it about then?

Comment: About calling a static method inside a class

Comment: @DarkBee `getListFromRu()` is not a static method

Comment: @deceze new static is only useful for the late static bindings, the OP's class does not extend any other class, so new static is pointless here.

Comment: @postrel It's useful to keep your class open to extensions. Using `static` allows you to `extend` your class and benefit from late static binding in *that* class.

Comment: @user5510975 you are welcome. You could extend your question to explain why you need to call `getListFromRu()` from an object context and not from a class context. My guess is that there's some business logic in the class constructor. You should really make that clear in your question. That could have avoided all the downvotes.